# how to create a matrix when two values are in the same groupby column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So i basically have a dataframe of products and orders:

```
product    order
 apple      111
 orange     111
 apple      121
 beans      121
 rice       131
 orange     131
 apple      141
 orange     141
```

What i need to do is, groupby the products based on the id of the order, and generate this matrix with the value of times they appeared together in the same order.
I don't know any efficient way of doing this, if someone could help me!

```
           apple   orange  beans rice
 apple       x        2      1     0
 orange      2        x      0     1
 beans       1        0      x     0
 rice        0        1      0     x
```

Comment: is your order value always numeric? what is the minimum and maximum order value? are the order values in sequential order or jumbled up?................... where do you get the order values from? from csv? if yes, please upload a sample of the csv (as file or text)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to join the dataframe with itself on `order` and then calculate the cooccurrences using `crosstab` on the two `product` columns:

```
df.merge(df, on='order').pipe(lambda df: pd.crosstab(df.product_x, df.product_y))

product_y  apple  beans  orange  rice
product_x                            
apple          3      1       2     0
beans          1      1       0     0
orange         2      0       3     1
rice           0      0       1     1
```

Comment: I don't see `pipe` often but definitely convenient to chain operation :) nice

Comment: @Ben.T I was about to post the other option, but you nailed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to perform a `crosstab` between product and order, then do a matrix multiplication `@` with the transpose so:

```
a_ = pd.crosstab(df['product'], df['order'])
res = a_@a_.T
print(res)
product  apple  beans  orange  rice
product                            
apple        3      1       2     0
beans        1      1       0     0
orange       2      0       3     1
rice         0      0       1     1
```

or using `pipe` to do a one liner:

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['product'], df['order']).pipe(lambda x: x@x.T)
```